node js, rabbitmq message is not sent but a success log is made
try {
  var connection = amqp.createConnection(config.amqp, { reconnect: false });
  var options;
  
  await Promise.fromNode(function (cb) {
    connection.on('ready', function () {
      connection.exchange("", options = { type: 'fanout', confirm: true }, function (exchange) {
        exchange.publish(queue, msg, { mandatory: true, deliveryMode: 2 }, cb);
      });
    });
    connection.on('error', cb);
  });

  rabbitmqLogger.info(
    `Message sent successfully , logType: %s, logName: %s, log_type: %s, log_category: %s, partition_keys: %s`, 
    msg, queue, 'business', 'ui_coreapi_rabbitmqLogs', 'core-api-logs', 'rabbitmqLogs', 'log_type,log_category'
  );
  connection.destroy();
  return;
} catch (err) {
  rabbitmqLogger.error(
    `Error sending message at ${retryCount+1} try, logType: %s, logName: %s, log_type: %s, log_category: %s, partition_keys: %s`, 
    err, msg, queue, 'business', 'ui_coreapi_rabbitmqLogs', 'core-api-logs', 'rabbitmqLogs', 'log_type,log_category'
  );
  connection.destroy();
}

here i get "Message sent successfully" but i dont see any message in rabbitmq, please help me with this
success log is made even before the message is sent to rabbitmq.
